# Text from my logger class to my richTextBox in my From1

Tags: c#, .net, events, logging

This is just a test to see how my Game manager program works that's why I want the text in my richTextBox.

I want to print all new lines in my log into my richTextBox, but I haven't found a good way to do it.

The way I have it now is that I print the last log entry in my log every 1 sec so I miss a lot of log lines.

How can I print out all the lines in my log not only the last log entry.

Form1

Timer is set to 1 sec.

```
private void timerRun_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine + MyLogger.GetLastLog();         
}
```

MyLogger

```
public static class MyLogger
{
    private static List<string> log = new List<string>();

    public static event EventHandler LogAdded;

    public static void Log(string message)
    {
        log.Add(message);

        if (LogAdded != null)
            LogAdded(null, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public static string GetLastLog()
    {
        if (log.Count > 0)
            return log[log.Count - 1];
        else
            return null;
    }        
}
```

Do anyone have any idea or example to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this to subscribe to your `LogAdded` event defined in `MyLogger` class

```
MyLogger.LogAdded += (s, e) =>
{
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker) (() =>
    {
        richTextBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine + MyLogger.GetLastLog();
    }));
};
```

some suggestion for better result

1. try to customize your event handler in `MyLogger` class so it reflect the new added log. so you can get new added log from the event args directly. after this change there is no need to call `GetLastLog()`
2. add `LogAdded += (s, e) => {}` to the static constructor of `MyLogger` class. after this change there is no need to check for nullability of `LogAdded` event.
3. you may access `MyLogger` from different threads. `MyLogger` is not thread safe, set up a synchronizing mechanism (use `Lock` for example) or use data structures defined in [System.Collections.Concurrent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx) (these are all thread safe)